uasyncio.Event not resuming main loop immediately after set on Raspberry Pi Pico
I'm programming in Micropython for the Raspberry Pi Pico. In my main loop I await for an uasyncio.Event, which I successfully set from an interrupt context.
I expected the code to pause and then resume soon after the event was set, but instead:

If the event was already set, it continues as expected
If the event was not set beforehand and there is no other tasks running, the program terminates without warning
If I create a keep_alive task that simply loops, the main loop will resume from the event wait just before the keep_alive tasks wakes up from sleep

Of course, setting the keep_alive sleep cycle very short minimizes the issue, but is very hacky.
It feels like waiting on an Event doesn't keep the loop alive by itself, and setting the event won't resume execution unless something else wake the loop
(both of which to me were unexpected)
Should I not be using Events to start with?
Finally, I also tried to trigger a wake up by creating a trivial task from IRQ context using schedule, but the task won't even start until the loop awakes on its own from a preexisting sleep
In the following code, 4 seconds pass between "set" and "end". I reckon that's because the main loop code doesn't resume when the Event is set, but when the uasyncio scheduler wakes up for the keep_alive task. Also, awake never prints because it resumes the main loop before that and terminates.
import uasyncio
from machine import Timer


async def keep_awake():
    while True:
        print("awake")
        await uasyncio.sleep(5)

def set(_=None):
    global event
    event.set()
    print("set")

async def main():
    print("start")

    # The time will call set() after a second
    Timer(-1).init(mode=Timer.ONE_SHOT, period=1000, callback=set)

    print("waiting...")
    global event
    await event.wait()
    print("end")


event = uasyncio.Event()
uasyncio.create_task(keep_awake())
uasyncio.run(main())



